# Glitch in C#-Syntax highlighter

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I just observed a small glitch in the C#-syntax-highlighter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590883/1521227):

[image]

The Word `Remove` should be completely black. Reproduced with IE9 and SRWare Iron.

**EDIT:** I retagged that to support, because this is no bug actually (See answers from animuson and Oded).

Comment: Whoops, moved on the close too quick, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some weird characters in between the "Re" and "move" parts of the text. It was actually:

```
Re&zwnj;&#8203;move
```

I've fixed it with a simple edit.

Comment: *argh* - Note to myself: First look at the code, then post a bug-report. Should I leave the post open for futher reference?

Comment: @Spontifixus - Even when you _look_ at the code you wouldn't see it (unless you mean view the html source). It is a _zero width_ space, so you don't see it. I found it by using the right arrow and finding an extra character where there wasn't one to be seen.

Comment: @Oded Oh well - thanks for clarifying At least now I know for the next time...

Answer (score 3):

There was a [Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character just after `.Re`.

Nothing wrong with the highlighter - unless you believe it should catch this.

Comment: No it shouldn't catch that...